# Reading keywords from a text file using array in java

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I am creating a program that reads keywords, from the array, and then matches this keywords to the sentences from a text file. I have created the array, and converted it into an arrayList.

```
String[] faults = { "Misspelled", "Error", "Fixed", "Change","Update", "Out of sync",
"Fail", "API Tooling","Unclear", "Charset", "Typos", "Fixed bug"};
 ArrayList newarray = new ArrayList(100);
newarray.addAll(Arrays.asList(faults));
```

I have read the file using the while loop and buffer reader, which reads the file by line as the each sentence is one line. But now I am stuck at how to read the keywords in the array, and match them to the words in the text file which contains sentences. Which in turns prints out all the sentences that matches all the the words in the array.

I would be great full for any help, or any suggestion on how I should do this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This line `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(faults));` isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it out without it. The results is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
String[] faults = { "Misspelled", "Error", "Fixed", "Change","Update", "Out of sync",
"Fail", "API Tooling","Unclear", "Charset", "Typos", "Fixed bug"};
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Azad.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line !=null)
            {
               for(int i = 0 ; i<faults.length;i++){
               if(line.contains(faults[i])){
                   // do something
                   System.out.println(faults[i]);
               }
               }
               line=reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you :) It works, but it doesn't print out the whole sentence e.g. Fixed for bug 392581 - Adding regression tests.

Answer (score 2):

Yes You Can by adding a counter

```
//.....
    //.....

        int count=0;
         while(line !=null)
         {
          for(int i = 0 ; i<faults.length;i++){
           if(line.contains(faults[i])){
              // do something
              System.out.println(line);
              count++;
          }
         }
       line=reader.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Printed Lines   = "+count);
//.....
//.....
```

Comment: Thanks you so much again :) I'm really great-full for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The same example just print  line  instead of faults[i]

```
//....
//....


    if(line.contains(faults[i])){
     // do something
     System.out.println(line);
    }
//.....
//....
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much :) Been working on this problem for days now.

Comment: Just one more question, is there anyway in which I can count how many numbers of lines is printed? Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a foreach loop:

```
for (String fault : faults) {
    //check if current sentence contains fault    
}
```

This loop also works for the ArrayList. Just replace faults with newArray.